# What is equivalent of windows' hosts file?

Tags: internet-connection, redirect

I want to redirect some sites to localhost. I can use `hosts` file which resides in directory `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc` in windows.

Which is equivalent of this file in Ubuntu?

Comment: Amusingly, the Windows hosts file is actually the equivalent of the Unix host file ; both files being kept in a folder called "etc" is a big clue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Ubuntu it is `/etc/hosts`. You can edit the file as same in other OSes.

Comment: What for then there is a `resolve.conf` in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Green post new questions as questions, not as comments. Also, the grammar is not clear in that sentence. Should be "If there is an `/etc/hosts` file in Ubuntu, why does Ubuntu have a `resolve.conf` file too?"